# having issue in Installing TFS 2013 in Reporting Services

Tags: iis, reporting-services, tfs

I am faceing a problem during my installation to TFS2013. After restore the backup databases, I follow the upgrade wizard. but in Configure Reporting for use with Team Foundation Server and when I press Populate URLs the URL got empty as following:
[image]

and in the readiness checks this message appears "One or more features that Team Foundation Services requires are not configured in Internet Information Services (IIS)".

It seems the TFS can't create websites on IIS, even the IIS fully uninstalled.

Kindly advice.

Comment: Silly question: Is reporting services installed and configured?

Answer (score 0):

use Reporting Services Configuration Manager and Choose an existing backed up report server database  and configure the url